# Not able to convert to datetime in pandas if i have different offset

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing, pandas-groupby

Not able to convert to date time if offset is different. 
For ex : i have records like
"
*2019-11-02 21:00:00-04:00,
2019-11-03 10:00:00-05:00*
". And this is due to DST change between 2nd November and 3rd November.

And when i do,

```
pd.to_datetime(raw_data['date'])
```

*o/p type is --> Name: date, dtype: object*

But when i convert separately for each record then i am able to convert exactly.

*o/p type is --> Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-300)]*